# Cartesian Product of a set with itself representing 1-d Euclidean space confusion.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm having a hard time seeing how 1D space can be defined under the definition of a metric space, specifically with regard to the use of the **Cartesian product**.

A pair, $(X,d)$ represents a metric. The set is $X$, and the distance function is $d$.

The distance function is defined however you wish, for instance $d(a,b)$ such that $a,b \in X$ can be equal to whatever so long as it holds to the axioms of a metric space.

1. $d(a,b) = d(b,a)$
2. $d(a,a) = 0$
3. $d(a,b)\geq 0$
4. $d(a,b) \leq d(a,c) + d(c,b)$

Now onto the point of confusion,

$d: X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$

In regards to the number line, how can it be defined by the Cartesian product of a set with itself?

I could define distance on the number line in this way,

$d:\mathbb{W}\times \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$d(a,b) := |a-b|$

The 1D line in this instance would be $\{(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), \dots, (n, 0)\}$

If you take the Cartesian product of a set with itself aren't you at least going to get a $2$ dimensional space?

Comment: $d : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ means you take two numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ and turn them into another number in $\mathbb{R}$. So $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ gets mapped to $|a - b| \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Soo   $d : \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ means you take two elements in $\mathbb R^2$ and turn them into a number in $\mathbb R$.  So $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ gets mapped to $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Well, that’s not the formula. What you want is to map $(a,b))$ to $b-a$ or $a-b$, whichever of these is nonnegative. Thus $\mid a-b\mid$. Just the distance between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: No, $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ is still just a map from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just a different way of writing $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. And as far as a metric space goes, it still doesn't work because it doesn't fit number 2. in your list of axioms.

Comment: Right, it doesn't fit axiom 2.  My main confusion with regards to notation was representing 1-d space using $\mathbb R^2$.  Is the idea that a coordinate, say (1,2)  in $\mathbb R^2$ can be treated as two points on a number line?  I'm still confused about the definition of a Metric space requiring that you take the Cartesian product of a set with itself.

Comment: Given these two sentences in your question, "1D space can be defined under the definition of a metric space" and "In regards to the number line, how can it be defined by the Cartesian product of a set with itself", I think this is just a misunderstanding of the basic function notation involved rather than a question about metric spaces or Cartesian products. The notation $$d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$$ does not, in any way, mean that $\mathbb R$ is *defined* to be the Cartesian product of $X$ with itself.